# Multiple types to a single type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to have a type that could be one or the other, I'm doing something like this:

```
type TestConfig = {
  file: string;
  name: string;
}

type CakeConfig = {
  run: string;
}

type MixConfig = { test: TestConfig | CakeConfig };

const typeCheck: MixConfig = {
  test: {
    run: 'run!'
  }
};


console.log(typeCheck.test.run)
```

But the type check fails with the following error:

Property 'run' does not exist on type 'TestConfig | CakeConfig'.
Property 'run' does not exist on type 'TestConfig'.

I was assuming that by using the union operator, I could have either one or the other, but looks that won't work. Any ideas on how to implement something simliar? Assuming that we don't know what the type would be, but could be one or the other.

Thanks!

Comment: "I was assuming that by using the union operator, I could have either one or the other" yes, that is correct. You have one *or the other*. The compiler doesn't know which, so you can't access a property that exists on one but not the other.

Comment: Thanks! That does make sense

Answer (score 1):

When you define a variable as a union, it means that that variable can be any of the items within the union. Therefore, TypeScript will assert that an operation is valid for all types within the union before you are able to do it. Therefore, if you did want your code to work when you know the type of the config at compile-time (like a constant object) and also when you dynamically create it (e.g. from some CLI input params) then you can create a helper function that simply wraps the config:

```
type TestConfig = {
  file: string;
  name: string;
}

type CakeConfig = {
  run: string;
}

function createConfig<T extends TestConfig | CakeConfig>(config: T): T extends TestConfig ? TestConfig : CakeConfig {
  return config as any; // cast is required for generic return
}

createConfig({ run: "hey" }); // CakeConfig
createConfig({ file: "", name: "" }); // TestConfig
createConfig({ run: "dynamic" } as any); // CakeConfig | TestConfig

// an example of the safe inference

const config = createConfig({ // CakeConfig
  run: 'run!'
});

declare function doSomething(config: TestConfig | CakeConfig): void;
doSomething(config); // works!

declare function doSomethingWithCake(config: CakeConfig): void;
doSomethingWithCake(config); // works!
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using your `typeCheck` like this:

```js
console.log(typeCheck.test.run)
```

This statement presupposes that `typeCheck.test` has a `run` property. At the same time `TestConfig` hasn't one. So it's a contradiction, because any variable of `MixConfig` type could have a `test` of `TestConfig`.

Thus to have this working, you have to add the `run` property to your `TestConfig`.

Answer (score 0):

You could cast `typeCheck.test` to a `CakeConfig` before accessing the `run` property:

```
console.log((typeCheck.test as CakeConfig)?.run);
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers stated, the interpreter cannot ensure `typeCheck.test` `CakeConfig`.

There is also a solution that creating a function to determine whether it is CakeConfig or not. It will be useful especially when the data is from outside.

```
function isCakeConfig(config: TestConfig | CakeConfig): config is CakeConfig {
  return config.hasOwnProperty("run")
}

if(isCakeConfig(typeCheck.test))
  console.log(typeCheck.test.run)
```